# $emit $broadcast synchronous or asynchronous?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Are `$scope.$emit()` and `$scope.$broadcast()` synchronous or asynchronous in the literal sense?

For example, in the cases

```
$scope.$emit()
console.log(" I am finished sending events");
```

and

```
$scope.$broadcast()
console.log(" I am finished sending events");
```

If all the listeners are synchronous (have no ajax calls etc) will the logging only happen after all listeners receive their events?

Answer (score 33):

They are synchronous.

See also https://groups.google.com/d/msg/angular/yyH3FYAy5ZY/APANNMnolD8J